# Development headers 'not found' when running passenger apache 2 module installer, but they are installed

Tags: apache2, passenger

I have been trying to install Passenger on a vps with the following:

- CentOS release 4.5 (Final)
- gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-8) box
- Apache/2.2.11 (Unix)
- Ruby Enterprise Edition
- Ruby 1.8.6
- Gem 1.3.5

I installed the gem

```
gem install passenger
```

when i run passenger-install-apache2-module I get the following message indicating I am missing development headers:

- GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
- Curl development headers with SSL support... not found
- OpenSSL development headers... not found
- Zlib development headers... not found
- Ruby development headers... found
- OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
- RubyGems... found
- Rake... found at /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090201/bin/rake
- rack... found
- Apache 2... found at /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd
- Apache 2 development headers... found at /usr/local/bin/apxs
- fastthread... found
- Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers... found at /usr/local/apache/bin/apr-1-config
- Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers... found at /usr/local/apache/bin/apu-1-config

I then following the provided instructions on how to install each:

```
# yum install curl-devel
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
update                    100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00     
base                      100% |=========================| 1.1 kB    00:00     
addons                    100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00     
extras                    100% |=========================| 1.1 kB    00:00     
Reading repository metadata in from local files
Parsing package install arguments
Nothing to do

# yum install openssl-devel
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
update                    100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00     
base                      100% |=========================| 1.1 kB    00:00     
addons                    100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00     
extras                    100% |=========================| 1.1 kB    00:00     
Reading repository metadata in from local files
Parsing package install arguments
Nothing to do

# yum install zlib-devel 
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
update                    100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00     
base                      100% |=========================| 1.1 kB    00:00     
addons                    100% |=========================|  951 B    00:00     
extras                    100% |=========================| 1.1 kB    00:00     
Reading repository metadata in from local files
Parsing package install arguments
Nothing to do
```

Does this indicate that they are already installed? Do I have to tell passenger where to find these? My site is currently down, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found this (http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=554) which is a slightly different issue, but ran through the solutions anyway, to no avail. Curl -V gives me the following:

Comment: curl 7.12.1 (i686-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.12.1 OpenSSL/0.9.7a zlib/1.2.1.2 libidn/0.5.6
Protocols: ftp gopher telnet dict ldap http file https ftps 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Comment: I installed glibc-devel which cleaned up the issues with OpenSSL and the Zlib. Still working on Curl

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem and solved it by doing this:

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel e2fsprogs-devel krb5-devel libidn-devel
```

That took care of it. I found this solution on the code.google.com site mentioned above, but noticed that there had been some new activity since this question was posted on Nov 24, 2010.

I followed the instructions in comment #18, and it worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: I experienced the same problem and adding these development libraries fixed it for me as well.